# Cloud storage extension for CKAN

Tags: amazon-s3, ckan

I am looking for an extension which enables CKAN to upload resources to cloud storage such as AWS S3. I am looking for something with decent support and supports latest CKAN version. So far I have looked in to;

**CKAN CloudConnector**
    https://extensions.ckan.org/extension/cloudconnector/

**CKAN Extension to upload resources to AWS S3**
    https://extensions.ckan.org/extension/s3-resources/

**Open Knowledge Foundation**
    https://github.com/okfn/ckanext-s3filestore

**ckanext-cloudstorage**
    https://github.com/open-data/ckanext-cloudstorage

**FileStore and File Uploads (Looks like no longer supported)**
    https://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-1.7.4/filestore.html#cloud-storage

I am new to CKAN space, so any help is highly appriciated.

Regards

Comment: s3filestore or cloudstorage can do the work, and are working with latest stable CKAN version

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the extentions you mentioned. But not all files were automatically uploaded to s3

Can you refer to the information below?

In this example we’ll enter the running ckan container to install ckanext-geoview from source, ckanext-showcase from GitHub, and ckanext-envvars from PyPi:

```sh
# Enter the running ckan container:
docker exec -it ckan /bin/bash -c "export TERM=xterm; exec bash"

# Inside the running container, activate the virtualenv
source $CKAN_VENV/bin/activate && cd $CKAN_VENV/src/

# Option 1: From source
git clone https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-geoview.git
cd ckanext-geoview
pip install -r pip-requirements.txt
python setup.py install
python setup.py develop
cd ..

# Option 2: Pip install from GitHub
pip install -e "git+https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-showcase.git#egg=ckanext-showcase"

# Option 3: Pip install from PyPi
pip install ckanext-envvars

# exit the ckan container:
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

I have chosen ckanext-cloudstorage https://github.com/open-data/ckanext-cloudstorage as the extension to use. Easy to setup and configure.

1. Install boto in your python virtual environment.
2. Install ckanext-cloudstorage extenstion.
3. Update ckan configuration (/etc/ckan/default/production.ini for me)
4. Restart apache2. Your newly added resources should start apperaring in your preferred cloud storage solution (S3 in my case).

I had some trouble with S3 permissions. So please make sure S3 setup is right. I used s3api commands to verify my access.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to add comments leaves me inquiries because I have a low score.

When I use ckanext-cloudstorage, if I upload a csv file to ckan datasets, will it automatically be uploaded to s3?